# Enrolling AFT-Provisioned Account in a Child OU

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-control-tower

I am trying to enroll an account created with the Account Factory Tool (AFT) into a child Organizational Unit (OU) within my AWS organization. However, I am currently unable to dynamically set the ManagedOrganizationalUnit parameter within the Terraform configuration to reference the desired child OU based on the OU ID and OU name.

ManagedOrganizationalUnit = "..."

I tried directly embedding the child OU ID and parent OU name within the ManagedOrganizationalUnit parameter for each Terraform module. However, this approach might not be supported depending on the specific configuration.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Can you share the AFT version you're using and the account creation TF code as well so we can better analyse the issue?